# Jquery.Ajax Отправка формы

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как при успешной проверке формы (data.result == true) выполнить action формы(перейти на страницу), а при ошибке (data.result == false) оставить человека на странице с сообщением об ошибке.

```
$("#reg").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "check.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#password").val() }),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.result == true) {
                    $(".information").text('Auth is succesfull');
                    } else if(data.result == false) {
                    $(".information").text(data.error_msg);
                }
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    })
```

Comment: вы можете перенаправить его на сервере в check.php

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать так, с помощью `window.location.href`.

```js
$("#reg").submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "check.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: ({ login: $("#login").val(), password: $("#password").val() }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.result == true) {
              //Здесь перенаправляем на какой то url вот так
              window.location.href = 'Здесь какой то url'
                //$(".information").text('Auth is succesfull');
            } else if(data.result == false) {
              //Ну а тут какое то оповещение на ваш вкус
                $(".information").text(data.error_msg);
            }
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Пробовал, тогда идет переадресация но без данных $_POST

Comment: Не понял тогда зачем вам `ajax`? просто сделаете простую форму и отправьте его в тот `url` который хотите. Вы вопрос не правильно задали.

Comment: Эмм, ну я хочу сделать чтобы если логин или пароль был неверен то пользователь оставался на странице без перезагрузки, а если все норм то его кидало на нужную страницу.

Comment: Ну тогда зачем вам данные формы при`success`? Вы знаете как надо сделать логин? и как сервер понимает человек залогинен или нет?

Answer (score 0):

> я хочу сделать чтобы если логин или пароль был неверен ...

А Вы не узнаете верен он или нет, пока не отправите форму.

Вот тут уже ajax пригодиться. 
Делается это примерно так: 
1. Посылаем форму через ajax (можно сначала проверить, что поля не пустые).
2. Получаем ответ сервера. Разбираем его. Может достаточно кода состояния, может надо в текст залезать. Как вариант-проверять cookie в ответе на предмет наличия session id или чего-то такого. 
3. Если авторизация прошла - переходим куда надо.
4. Если не прошла -

В общем-то код выше должен работать, только надо как-то иначе обрабатывать ответ сервера (а может и так сойдет - смотреть надо).